# Sequelize get all records if value exists on N:N table

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I want to achieve this query with sequelize

```
SELECT U.username, G.groupName
FROM [user] U INNER JOIN [userGroup] UG ON (U.id = UG.userId) INNER JOIN [group] G ON (G.id = UG.groupId)
WHERE U.profileId = @profile AND EXISTS (SELECT groupId FROM [userGroup] WHERE groupId = @group AND userId = U.id)
```

the expected result are all the users that match with the profile and all theirs groups in which some group should be present

this is my relevant code of my associations layer

```
db.users.belongsToMany(db.group, {
  as: 'Groups',
  through: UserGroup,
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  otherKey: 'groupId',
});
db.group.belongsToMany(db.users, {
  as: 'Users',
  through: UserGroup,
  foreignKey: 'groupId',
  otherKey: 'userId',
});
```

and the one from the controller

```
User.findAll({
   where: {profileId = Number(profileType)},
   include: [{
      model: Group,
      as: 'Groups',
      attributes: ['groupName'],
      where: [
        {
          [Op.and]: sequelize.literal(
            `EXISTS (SELECT [UG].groupId FROM [userGroup] AS [UG] WHERE [UG].groupId = ${group})`
          ),
        };
      ]
      required: true,
   }]
```

My principal problem is how to filter by userId in the sequelize subquery like i did in the SQL query example from the begining

Comment: So do you want to filter by `userId` or by `groupId` as I can see here `groupId = ${group}`?

Comment: @Anatoly i want to filter by both (userId and groupId) but i dont know how to make a reference on the subquery to the id of the User table like i did in the SQL query from the beginning

Comment: @shawnt00 if i add UserGroups model to the include array, i get a SequelizeEagerLoadingError, i think that is because the table is N:N and the required option in false didn't help

Comment: You need to move this subquery condition to the Users's conditions because you have `AND userId = U.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this subquery condition to the User's conditions because you have `AND userId = U.id`. Something like this:

```js
User.findAll({
   where: {
      [Op.and]: [{
        profileId = Number(profileType)
      }, 
      sequelize.literal(
            `EXISTS (SELECT [UG].groupId FROM [userGroup] AS [UG] WHERE [UG].groupId = ${group} AND [UG].userId=[User].id)`
          )]
   },
   include: [{
      model: Group,
      as: 'Groups',
      attributes: ['groupName'],
      required: true,
   }]
```

You should look at generated SQL query and correct the `[User]` table alias if needed in `AND [UG].userId=[User].id`